# How DTO is binded in Entity framework internally

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Actually I am trying to create a generic library for CRUD operation using DTO(POCO class).

But in API we have many complex Request and Response. So am I want to create my own format for doing the CRUD operation. So I am trying to understand how DTO is binding in Entity Framework so that I can create a logic in such a way that I can save any DTO directly in database.

For Example

when we save anything in database using entity framework, we just pass the full DTO object like this.

```
context.Add(author);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Here in my case author DTO have more property which is not used for saving purpose, the extra property is used when I send response.So this extra property throw error says this extra property not match with the column when I save by this code

```cs
context.Add(author);
context.SaveChanges();
```

So in simple I want to create a generic method where I can send as many property in DTO, But it save only those property which is matching with the database table.

**Here with complete detail**

**(Scenario-1)**
Suppose I have DTO Author

```cs
class Author
{
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
    public int AuthorName {get;set;}
    public int AuthorAge {get;set;}
}
```

There is a table with columns

```
AuthorId
AuthorName
AuthorAge
```

When I save this using

```cs
context.Add(author);
context.SaveChanges();
```

It working fine.

**(Scenario-2)**

```cs
class Author
{
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
    public int AuthorName {get;set;}
    public int AuthorAge {get;set;}
}

class Book : Author
{
    public int BookId {get;set;}
    public int BookName {get;set;}
}
```

And the table with column

```
BookId ,
BookName ,
AuthorId
```

In this scenario when I am save the data using

```cs
context.Add(books);
context.SaveChanges();
```

it will give error.

And by doing [NotMapped] for AuthorName ,AuthorAge will not save the record in scenario 1.

I hope you understand what i want to say.

Comment: This is quite simple. Just add the `[NotMapped]` attribute to every property which you do not want to save in the DataBase

Comment: But the same DTO is used in many scenario by other method for response purpose which uses that extra property to bind the data from database table which have that property name.

Comment: So the property is only used sometimes?

Comment: Yes. The property is used only sometime.

Comment: Could you expand your question and add an example of a DTO class with the attribute that is used only sometimes? Also, what is stopping you from saving the property to the database as just NULL (not required in the Database)?

Comment: I have update the question in detail. Please have a look

Comment: `class Book : Author` is a nonsensical relation. A book isn't an author. A book **has** one or more authors.

Comment: In the second scenario, are you actually saving an instance of the Author class or an instance of the Book class? Also, inheritance here is wrong. A Book is not an Author and therefore shouldn't inherit from Author. Instead, a Book has an Author (and sometimes multiple, but I'll ignore it for now) so there should be a reference instead.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Book **IS** definitely not an Author

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance in this case is wrong. When inheriting from something you should ask yourself this: "Is X also Y?" in this case "Is Book an Author?", which it isn't. A Book has an Author, so instead of inheriting from Author we'll need a reference to it.

In normal classes we'd just do this:

```cs
public class Book
{
    public Author Author {get; set;}
}
```

but because this isn't a normal class, instead it's a Model for Entity Framework we need to do this:

```cs
public class Book
{
    public int BookId {get; set;}
    public string BookName {get; set;}
    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
    public virtual Author Author {get; set;}
}
```

Keeping your Author class like this

```cs
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
    public int AuthorName {get; set;}
    public int AuthorAge {get; set;}
}
```

On the database this creates two tables:

```
Author Table:
|AuthorId|AuthorName|AuthorAge|
|--------|----------|---------|
|...     |...       |...      |
|--------|----------|---------|

Book Table:
|BookId|AuthorId|BookName|
|------|--------|--------|
|...   |...     |...     |
|------|--------|--------|
```

Where the `AuthorId` in the Book table is a foreign key onto the Author tables `AuthorId`

You can now access the Authors information of any book easily by doing `book.Author.AuthorName`.

P.S Please note that the tables are examples, the actual names of them and the names of the columns aren't what EF will generate in your database. They merely serve demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're missing the Layers, Your `DTO` are only `DTO` (Data Transfer Objects) that will flow between methods/commands/queues and you should have your `DbModel` that are the `partial` clases that are properties in your `DbContext`

`DbContext`

```
public partial class BookStoreContext : DbContext
{
  public BookStoreContext(DbContextOptions<BookStoreContext> options) : base(options)
  {
  }

  public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
}
```

`DbModels`

```
public partial class Author
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
  public virtual List<Book> Books {get;set;}
}


public partial class Book
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int AuthorId {get;set;}
  public virtual Author Author {get;set;}

}
```

`DTO`

```
class AuthorTo
{
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
    public int AuthorName {get;set;}
    public int AuthorAge {get;set;}
}

class BookTo : AuthorTo
{
    public int BookId {get;set;}
    public int BookName {get;set;}
}
```

And the magic resides in a library like [`AutoMapper`](https://automapper.org/), that will help you to map your DTO's to a `Model`

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
  cfg.CreateMap<BookTo, Book>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BookId))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BookName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AuthorId)));
```

Then you can `Map` your `DTO` to a `Model`

```
...


var book = mapper.Map<BookTo, Book>(bookTo);
context.Add(books);
context.SaveChanges();

...
```

Hope this helps you :)

[AutoMapper docs](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html)

[How to get started with AutoMapper and ASP.NET Core 2](https://medium.com/ps-its-huuti/how-to-get-started-with-automapper-and-asp-net-core-2-ecac60ef523f)

Answer (score -1):

This is how I'd have written my classes

```
  public class Author
            {
            public int AuthorId {get;set;}
            public string AuthorName {get;set;}
            public int AuthorAge {get;set;}
            public virtual List<Book> Books {get;set;}
            }



 public partial class Book
    {
           public int BookId {get;set;}
           public string BookName {get;set;}
           public int AuthorId {get;set;}
           public virtual Author Author {get;set;}

    }

 public partial class Book
   {
     public string AuthorName {get{return Author.AuthorName;}}
     public int AuthorAge {get{return Author.AuthorAge;}}
   }
```

Comment: Other than being very poorly formatted, your answer doesn't attempt to explain anything. Also, if Book has reference to Author as a Property, you shouldn't add the properties of Author on to Book as this is just redundant

Comment: `class Book : Author` shows that he wants access to the Author Properties from the Book level.  That's what I did.

Comment: So why add redundant properties to the Book class instead of just doing `book.Author.AuthorName`?

Comment: typing `book.Author.AuthorName` over and over gets old when with 5 lines of code I don't have to type the extra Author everytime.

Comment: This is an incredibly stupid reason to add every single property of every class that you have a reference to to your class. Also it just confuses people that don't know the code. Is `book.AuthorName` the same as `book.Author.AuthorName`? (easy to answer here but less in other cases) And also, what if you add properties to the Author class? You then also need to update every single class that references it, manually, which is error prone

Comment: I tend to agree with @MindSwipe here. I would certainly not create simply duplicated author-related properties in the `Book` class here. Besides that, what if you add a property that is contained in both classes? Always use unique prefixes, perhaps? To be honest, I personally would not prefix the class properties with their class name (like the OP did here). I would have used property `Name` both in class `Book` and in class `Author`, and if I had a `Book` instance `myBook`, property `myBook.Name` could return "Oliver Twist" and property `myBook.Author.Name` could return "Charles Dickens".